# Integrating $\log(x)\cdot\exp(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I evaluate $\int \log(x) e^x\;dx ?$
I tried to do integration by parts...

$$\int\log(x) \; dx = (x-1)\log(x) $$

Let $I=\int\log(x) e^x \; dx$.
Therefore,
$$
I = (x-1)\log(x) e^x - \int (x-1)\log(x) e^x \; dx
$$
$$= (x-1)\log(x) e^x - \int (x)\log(x) e^x \; dx +\int \log(x) e^x \; dx$$
$$= (x-1)\log(x) e^x - \int  x \log(x) e^x \; dx + I$$

Now what to do, $I$ is on both LHS and RHS??

Comment: It is, but you made your integral more complicated... so I don't think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall $$\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x, \frac{d}{dx} \log x = \frac{1}{x}.$$ Now, integrate by parts
$$ \int e^x \log x \ dx = e^x \log x \color{red}{-} \int \frac{e^x}{x} dx = e^x \log x \color{red}{-} \operatorname{Ei}(x) + c$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ is [Exponential Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

---

As noted in the comment by Patrick, and this paragraph in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions):

> $\int \frac{e^x}{x} dx $ is not an [elementary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), a fact which can be proven using the [Risch Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_Algorithm).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28e%5Ex%2Fx%2C+dx%29

Comment: In case you don't notice, J.D.'s answer means that if no one has a closed formula for the exponential integral, then no one has a closed formula for the integral you are looking for. This means that you can't hope (I believe) to "compute it" as you wished.

Comment: I believe it is $e^x \log x - \operatorname{Ei}(x) + c$

Comment: @KirthiRaman of course. Thanks.