# How to integrate this integral $\int_{1}^{e}e^{x}\ln(x)\textrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've tried integration by parts to solve this integral but no luck

> $$\int_{1}^{e}e^{x}\ln(x)\textrm{d}x$$

from WA

- [image]
- [image]

Any input, be it a gentle nudge or full solution, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule

Comment: Thanks but i already know how to integrate by parts

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119520/integrating-logx-cdot-expx

Comment: Are you sure you got this right? Is this homework, do you expect it to have some simple result? Some context?

Comment: This is not homewrok i'm just found it and i'm trying to solve it

Answer (score 1):

$$\int e^x\ln(x)\,{\rm d}x$$

$$=e^x\ln(x)-\int\frac{e^x}{x}\,{\rm d}x$$

As I am sure you can get. The second integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions and it is called $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ also known as the exponential integral.

Comment: I guess that the fact that is a definite integral should help somehow?

Comment: @leonbloy Usually yes, but [looks like not in this case](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/119524/127574)

Comment: WA fails too:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28%28e%5Ex%29log%28x%29+dx%29+from+1+to+e